# blurry images when setting background

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem setting background images. For some reason whenever I try to set the background image of a div, the image renders very blurry. Someone said to make the images 2x bigger but that didn't work. This also happens when I try to set a background image on the body. It also happens with videos. When I set a video to take the full width of the body, the video becomes blurry. Does anyone know why this might be happening. I've also tried setting the `background-size` to contain or cover instead of a percentage, but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

here's an example of my code:

```css
.container{
    top: 5.2rem;
    position: relative;
    background-color: pink;
    padding-bottom: 30rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/images/portfolio-image6.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: What's the resolution of `portfolio-image6.jpg`?

Comment: the resolution is 825x585

Comment: Please make a runnable snippet which shows the problem (so you'll need to include an image we can see). What is setting the height of container (apsrt from the padding) and what size viewports show the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth can i send you my code?

Comment: The code needs to be in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. And note that if your viewport width is greater than the natural width of the image you are going to get some blurriness.